# Where is Ubuntu Groovy kernel git

Tags: kernel, source

I can't find the 5.8 `groovy` kernel git at

https://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/

Have the maintainers moved it anywhere? How can I find the kernel source git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my 20.10 test VM I see the following:

> ```
> $ apt-get source linux-headers-`uname -r`
> Reading package lists... Done
> Picking 'linux' as source package instead of 'linux-headers-5.8.0-25-generic'
> NOTICE: 'linux' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
> git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/groovy
> Please use:
> git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/groovy
> to retrieve the latest (possibly unreleased) updates to the package.
> Need to get 182 MB of source archives.
> Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main linux 5.8.0-25.26...
> ```

So it says that ubuntu kernel sources are located at `git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/groovy`.

Other way to find the sources - is to use search on https://packages.ubuntu.com and go to [`linux-meta` package page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/groovy/linux-meta).

So you can browse it at

[https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/groovy](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/groovy)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited the answer to make it full.

Comment: Great! I appreciate it.

Comment: I was asking where I could browse the code. You gave a perfect hint. They moved it.